# c# Form submit viewstate error

Tags: c#, webforms, viewstate

Im trying to setup a login functionallity in C#, where I have a form on default.aspx that posts to Login.aspx where the logic is runned.

But when the form posts to Login.aspx I get a MAC viewstate verification error. What is this and why?

When I call Login.aspx direct from the browser I get no error, only when the form posts itself to it.

Default.aspx form code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Login.aspx">
<div>
  <input type="text" name="lgn" id="lgn" runat="server" /> Login<br />
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" runat="server" /> Password<br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
```

Is there any restrictions to posting a form to another page in the same project, or is there anny setting i have missed?

### Thanks in advance

I solved it by using the PostBackURL property on a asp:button instead of the action property on the form tagg, like so:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="login" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
```

Comment: Can you translate the messages after both "HttpException (0x80004005)"s into english?

Comment: Validation of a MAC viewstate failed. If the application program in a Web group or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. Auto Generate can not be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to be using the the following

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClickie" Text="Click Me" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
```

instead of setting the action for the form to Login.aspx, but you'll have to pull the previous page's data.  You can register the previous page with this...

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Page1.aspx" %>
```

Then you'll be able to pull the controls from the other page (provided they have runat="server" on them).  At least in theory.

http://aspalliance.com/135 has a fair article on ViewState, but it doesn't have a smoking gun for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way these forms work is posting back to themselves (and then maybe redirecting to another page).

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have multiple webserver with load-balancing routers in front. I've written a blog post about that. [Read it here](http://blog.js-development.com/2009/07/server-error-validation-of-viewstate.html). You basically have to add the machineKey setting to your web.config specifying a validation and decryption key. That will ensure it is the same on all machines. If none is specified, it will be autogenerated.